# How can I check whether neighbor (previous and next) digits in a row differ in 1 (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, list, integer, compare

is it possible to create a code(without list comprehensions, please) that will compare whether neighbor (previous and next) digits in a row differ in 1 so if the condition is met returns the row and returns "good", if not met - "bad". Also, the difference between  9 and 0 doesn't consider as 1. Besides, I need to check whether the only one-digit number and return "one digit" then.  I see for me just now it's tricky, so please help!
For example:

```
for (12345432): 
    return "good"                                                                  
for (1793):
    return "bad"
for (7):
    return "one digit"
```

`

Comment: So, do you have an integer, or list of integers/strings? The code you've provided isn't valid Python

Comment: No, integer, not list! I provided no code, just a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution (with check for one digit):

```py
i = 12345432

if i < 10:
    print("One Digit")
else:
    for a, b in zip(str(i), str(i)[1:]):
        if abs(int(a) - int(b)) != 1:
            print("Bad")
            break
    else:
        print("Good")
```

Prints:

```
Good
```